# Maintain input focus while not the main window

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I'm currently starting to write a WinForms application that will need to receive input from Dictation software while Focus is not on the application. I've been searching for clues and the best I have found so far are keyboard focus solutions or trying to use hooks. If anyone has some idea where to start or a hint please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Keyboard focus solutions or using hooks is what you'll need when you can't control the dictation software.  Contact the vendor for support.